# plotting parameters (e.g. xlim and ylim) in R markdown document behave differently on different machines

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

A friend and I are writing a document in R Markdown, which includes some super basic phylogenetic tree diagrams. We have run into a strange issue, where the same R markdown document produces different looking plots depending on which one of us knits the document. On my friend's machine, the plots look fine. On my machine, the borders of the plot look radically different, creating excess whitespace around the diagram.

The code we're using is as follows:

```
library(ape)

my_newick <- "(((A,B),C),D);"
my_tree <- read.tree(text = my_newick)

plot(my_tree,
direction = "downwards", srt = 90,
label.offset = 0.2,
adj = 0.5,
x.lim = c(0,5),
y.lim = c(0,10), no.margin = T)
```

On my friend's machine, the knitted PDF result looks like this:

[image: Nicely knitted page, with top tree diagram aligned nicely with text and little whitespace]

On my machine, the result looks like this:

[image: Ugly knitted page, with top tree diagram shrunken and a lot of whitespace around the diagram]

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas as to why the same code in the same document would produce different-looking figures like this? Is there something basic I'm missing here, like some global settings in my R installation to do with plotting? <s>Or could it be because we're using different R versions? (I'm lagging behind on 3.6.2, I think my friend may be using v4. That's about the only difference I can think of. We're knitting the same document and we both use Mac OS.)</s> Edit: Double-checked this and we're both using identical versions of R (3.6.2). I'm using v5.4-1 of the ape package vs his 5.3, but that's it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your friend's machine has tools to crop figures: [`pdfcrop`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) and [`ghostscript`](https://www.ghostscript.com/). These tools are probably not installed on your machine. Since you didn't provide your `sessionInfo()`, I don't know your platform, so it's hard to provide specific instructions on installation. If your LaTeX distribution is TinyTeX, `pdfcrop` can be installed via `tinytex::tlmgr_install('pdfcrop')`. Note that if you are on Windows, you will need to install Perl for `pdfcrop`. If you are on macOS, `ghostscript` can be installed via Homebrew.